# How can I repeat the last line in the Clojure REPL?

Tags: clojure, clojure-repl

In bash or Ruby's IRB, I can run a command or evaluate an expression, then use the up arrow on my keyboard to edit and rerun the same code. (This may be something I have configured, but I don't think so.)

This doesn't work for me in the Clojure REPL; I just see `^[[A` typed when I press the up arrow.

Is there a way to "retype" the last line?

Comment: Hmmm, hitting the left arrow to edit the line I'm working on produces similar output. Maybe this is a problem with my machine?

Comment: how do you start your repl?

Comment: @Jonas - using `java -cp clojure-1.5.1.jar clojure.main` or the shorter version after setting the CLASSPATH variable. (I'm just trying some Getting Started tutorials.)

Comment: try `rlwrap java -cp clojure-1.5.1.jar clojure.main`
Also, take a look at lein (http://leiningen.org) which most clojure programmers use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in comments [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) is picking up where a native Clojure REPL is not "doing it", including arrow navigation, history and more.

However most (if not all) of the time Clojure is used together with [`lein`](http://leiningen.org/), which has a built in REPL. Every time a Clojure REPL is needed, you can do:

```
lein repl
```

You don't necessarily need to have a project to start it, it can be started from anywhere (given that you have `lein` in your `PATH`) and has many other *very nice* properties, which `rlwrap` won't give you.

To name a few:

- If you run it form under the root of your project, it will load project's classpath, so you can *interact* with all the libs and code of your project.
- It will also start an [`nREPL`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl) which you can connect to from anywhere (local/remote) including your favorite IDE/editors that are "nREPL capable". This would allow (for example) `vim` or `emacs` to use that REPL you started with `lein repl` to evaluate, compile, navigate (source) right from the editor.
- Before it starts it reads and "obeys" `~/.lein/profiles.clj`, where you can configure your sessions with pretty much anything you want: gpg keys, repl-options, dependencies, plugins, etc.. which will be loaded/configured on the `lein repl`